# How can AirDrop be disabled?

Tags: macos, airdrop

I want to disable AirDrop so that my users do not have access to it but I have not been able to find a place to disable this feature.

The closest thing i have found is [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=12997287&postcount=12) but I don't know where to disable it.

Could someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "my users"? Non-administrative users on your computer?

Comment: @Daniel non administrative users on many computers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*System-wide*

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkBrowser DisableAirDrop -bool YES
```

*User-specific (via preferences)*

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkBrowser DisableAirDrop -bool YES
```

Comment: needed sudo for it to work but that did the trick

Comment: there is no UI for that ?

Comment: [This doesn't work for me.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/270711/4395)