# How do I disable AirDrop in the macOS Share menu?

Tags: macos, airdrop

The settings for the Share menu provide no option for disabling AirDrop:

[image]

Is there some other way to accomplish this? Instructions at [How can AirDrop be disabled?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/how-can-airdrop-be-disabled) have no effect.